# How to design a 2nd order LP active filter with differents responses?

Tags: circuit-design, filter, simulation, active-filter, control-theory

I have been asked to design and simulate a 2nd order analog low pass filter having the responses of Butterworth, Chebyshev and Bessel.

Im looking for guidance and suggestions,since I understand the theory but it seems too bloated to me and I don't know how to start and develop the process.

The starting concepts is the responses works as all pole filters, the zeros are at \$s=\infty\$, and all the poles are in the letf side of the complex plane.
The transfer function is based in the biquadratic function , with the indexes \$k_2=k_1=0\$ and \$k_0=1\$, then it is
\$H(s)=\frac{K(\omega_0)^2}{s^2+(\omega_0/Qs+(\omega_0)^2}\$
K is the gain in DC, now I dont know how to continue, I wasn't provided design parameters, gain, bandwith,etc, and in order to get the desired resonses , the coeficients of the transfer function must be adjusted, but it is unknown to me how to work it out.

Which is the process to do the designs ?
How to know if the desings are fine, if there is no parameters given?(I mean how much tolerance can be allowed to consider the desings ok).

*Note*
The \$k\$ are constants from the
\$H(s)=K\frac{k_{2}s^{2}+k_{1}(\omega_{o}/Q)s+k_{0}\omega_{o}^{2}}{s^{2}+(\omega_{o}/Q)s+\omega_{o}^{2}}\$

\$\omega_{o}\$ undamped natural frequency

\$Q\$ quality factor

\$K\$ DC gain

Constants \$k_{2}\$, \$k_{1}\$, and \$k_{0}\$ are \$\pm1\$ or \$0\$

Comment: Some informations can be given by simulators, so use one. http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm   use version 12, it is free, within the menu, there is a "design" for such filters. There is also many others software for these. https://rf-tools.com/lc-filter/

Comment: Can help you searching low-pass filter ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275650/multiple-feedback-low-pass-filter-design?rq=1

Comment: Are you in the same classroom as [this user](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/593050/95619)? What's k1 and k2? At any rate, you could start from the lowpass prototype transfer functions for [Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_filter) and [Butterworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter), and use some value for the passband ripple for [Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter). Hint: it's all about the quality factor.

Comment: @Antonio51, yeah very useful. Thanks.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, Nein.

Comment: @avelardo The fractional bandwidth, \$\frac{f_{_\text{H}}\:-\: f_{_\text{L}}}{f_{_\text{0}}}\$, makes a huge difference in approach. You are free to create anything at all?

Comment: @jonk, indeed, the only requeriments provided are the responses and the roll of -20db(?), but I think the roll of rate is wrong since if it is of 2n order should be -40db. And Im starting to see how to  work it out , precisely with the information you have provided.

Comment: @avelardo No, for 2nd order *bandpass* you'll get 20 on one side and 20 on the other.

Comment: @jonk, thanks Mr. Jonk, the filter is mean to be a low pass.

Comment: @avelardo As I commented out in the link, use this transfer function: $$H(s)=\dfrac{1}{s^2+as+1}$$ and change \$a\$ such that the quality factor makes it a Bessel (\$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\$), Butterworth (\$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$), or a Chebyshev (anything higher than Butterworth). You'll need to normalize the frequency if you're to match them. Just curious, why did you answer with "nein"?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, because you asked if Im in the same school of other user. No. I forgot to write in english

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, thanks, at least can I connect all the info in my head. Sometimes I recall the facts but it takes me time to make sense of that.

Comment: @avelardo Wollen wir uns duzen? No need to use Herr with me. :) Okay. So it's low-pass. Then yes, 40 db per decade down with 2nd order. As a concerned citizen writes, all 2nd order low-pass filters can be studied through changing only a single, real-valued parameter **a**. This is by setting the angular frequency to 1 (why bother with a different value while studying?) I'd like to recommend that you get and read Sallen & Key's paper -- either their Lincoln Labs TR-50 paper from 1954 or their later *A practical method of designing RC active filters* (which is much truncated.)

Comment: @jonk, Danke schön!!! verstehen Sie, und Sie sind sehr nett, Meister Jonk!!.  Indeed, I  become to  conclude it was a single variable modifying the whole response, but sometimes its confused and takes me so much time to link and process the theory, and there is a whole bunk of projects to build and present.  I was wondering too, why all the literature have \$\omega\$ set to 1.? =p,aber,this should be done this way in order to get the transfer function normalizated? I will post the progress asap.  Vielen Dank für Ihre gesamte große Hilfe !! In this question and all You have answered before!

Comment: @jonk, and thanks for the recommendations, I'll look forward to it.

Comment: @avelardo The formula generates a curve over frequency that ranges in shape from an over-damped shape, into a critically damped shape, and then over into an under-damped shape. The only varying parameter being **a**. Including \$\omega_{_0}\$ only serves to confuse the matter. It only affects the **x**-axis values. The curve shapes don't change any. So that why, when first learning this stuff,  \$\omega_{_0}=1\$ to remove one useless, unimportant parameter that would otherwise require more writing that doesn't serve to clarify anything. It's set to 1 to sweep away unnecessary details.

Comment: @avelardo Also see if you can find Don Lancaster's *"Active Filter Cookbook."* It's very old (1975), but also because of that directed in a way to teach hobbyists and wasn't intended to be part of some university coursework. So it starts early and teaches better than many books. It could still use some added help along the way, agreed. But it is easier than most to follow. Bear in mind that it uses terms that have fallen away, a bit. For example, we now use the unitless \$\zeta\$ as a replacement for his **d**, which isn't quite the same. Some help matching these up may be desired.

Comment: @jonk perhaps the books is my files, and perhaps I have dismissed because of the date. That's right, sometimes it is needed a different approach, since its a bit dificult to chew all the theory without a sample about what are you doing.